# Set selected value for select menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set selected value for select menu. Values are coming from $stateParams. So I am using ui-router and select menu is in the child state. Here is what i try.

This is works but i cant pull the i.

Javascript:

```
.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {
var milo = $stateParams.serix;
var musti = $stateParams.klasor;
MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen, milo, musti) {
var i;
for (i=0; i<loHemen.length; i++) {
    if (loHemen[i].seri===milo) {
       break;
    };

};
console.log(i);
$scope.mangalar = loHemen;
$scope.selManga = $scope.mangalar[0];
});

.factory('MMG', function($http){
var fveg= {};
var url = 'http://api.example.com/manga?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
fveg.adlar = $http.jsonp(url);
return fveg;
})
```

Html:

```
<select ng-model="selManga" ng-options="manga.seri for manga in mangalar">
    <option value="">Select a Manga</option>
</select>
```

JSON:

```
[{"seri": "Naruto",
  "randomword": [{
            "klasor": "138",
            "yol": [
            ]
        },
        {
            "klasor": "300",
            "yol": [

            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
 "seri": "One Piece",
 "randomword": [
        {
            "klasor": "137",
            "yol": [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
])
```

Comment: Seems like for loop will always return the `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop logic isn't totally correct.  If the body of the loop gets executed then your success function will return `i` (which will be 0) and the rest of the function body will not be run.  You should move the if condition to inside the loop.

```
.controller('nbgCtrl',function  ($scope, MMG, $stateParams) {
    var milo = $stateParams.serix;
    var musti = $stateParams.klasor;
    // remove the milo and musti variables in your promise callback
    // or if you actually want to have the response code and the headers,
    // give them appropriate variable names
    MMG.adlar.success(function(loHemen) {
        var i, miloMangaInArray;
        for (i=0; i<loHemen.length; i++) {
            if (loHemen[i].seri===milo) {
                miloMangaInArray = loHemen[i];
                break;
            }
        };
        console.log('found value or undefined',miloMangaInArray);
        $scope.mangalar = loHemen;
        $scope.selManga = miloMangaInArray;
    });
})
```

Comment: `Console.log` says its undefined.

Comment: If you are getting undefined then that means that it wasn't found in the array.  If you do a console.log with the value of `loHemen` and with `milo` what output do you get?

Comment: `console.log(milo)` inside of function gives `200` but outside of function gives correct value. I dont understan this its because `MMG` from factory?

Comment: That's because it's the result of the `$http` call.  If you look at the documentation for `HttpPromise` at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http, the parameters that are called with the promise fn are `(data,status,headers,config,statusText)`.  Because you are using the name `milo` for that variable, you are loosing access to the real `milo` call before.  I will update my sample to show you how it should work